# Does SwiftUI LazyHStack / LazyVStack still work if the ForEach loop nested?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my code

```swift
LazyHStack(spacing: spacing) {
   InnerView(data: self.data) // The for loop is contained inside the InnerView
}

LazyHStack(spacing: spacing) {
   ForEach(data, id: \.self) { viewDataMap in
       buildView(viewDataMap: viewDataMap)
   }
}
```

Does the "Lazyness" work for both code segments?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem. I am asking if it is still lazy or not. I am curious to know how it works. Depending on what I find out here, then I can proceed to building more on the app. But I do not want to hit unforeseen issues once it becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work as you expected. The Lazy property takes effect only when you have more items than your screen can show. If the number of items you have in your view fits in your screen, it doesn't have sense to use Lazy stacks.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but Previews crash on Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

Reported to feedbackassistant

> FB9121009 (Previews crash if LazyVStack contains two nested ForEach where Data.Element : Identifiable)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct NestedForEachInLazyVStack: View {

    var items1 = (0..<3).map { _ in Item() }
    var items2 = (0..<3).map { _ in Item() }

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items1) { _ in
                    ForEach(items2) { _ in
                        Text("text")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
}

struct NestedForEachInLazyVStack_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NestedForEachInLazyVStack()
    }
}
```